# Migration to test net works, but not to main net

Tags: ether, contract-deployment, truffle-migration, truffle-deployment, smart-contract-wallets

I am trying to deploy my contract to the ETH mainnet / livenet.

Everything works fine for the testnet, and also the dry-run for the mainnet works, but not the actual migration.

Here is the output:

```
truffle migrate --network live                                                                                                                                                                                                     1 ⨯

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.



Migrations dry-run (simulation)
===============================
> Network name:    'live-fork'
> Network id:      1
> Block gas limit: 30029267 (0x1ca35d3)


1_migration.js
======================

   Deploying 'TestContract'
   ----------------------
   > block number:        13060683
   > block timestamp:     1629442749
   > account:             <my_account>
   > balance:             0.086514396
   > gas used:            3742802 (0x391c52)
   > gas price:           2 gwei
   > value sent:          0 ETH
   > total cost:          0.007485604 ETH

   -------------------------------------
   > Total cost:         0.007485604 ETH


Summary
=======
> Total deployments:   1
> Final cost:          0.007485604 ETH





Starting migrations...
======================
> Network name:    'live'
> Network id:      1
> Block gas limit: 29970705 (0x1c95111)


1_migration.js
======================

   Deploying 'TestContract'
   ----------------------


Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"TestContract" could not deploy due to insufficient funds
   * Account:  <my_account>
   * Balance:  94000000000000000 wei
   * Message:  insufficient funds for gas * price + value
   * Try:
      + Using an adequately funded account
      + If you are using a local Geth node, verify that your node is synced.

    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/deployer/src/deployment.js:365:1
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at Migration._deploy (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/Migration.js:70:1)
    at Migration._load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/Migration.js:56:1)
    at Migration.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/Migration.js:217:1)
    at Object.runMigrations (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:150:1)
    at Object.runFrom (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:110:1)
    at Object.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:87:1)
    at runMigrations (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/migrate.js:258:1)
    at Object.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/migrate.js:221:1)
    at Command.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/command.js:172:1)
Truffle v5.4.5 (core: 5.4.5)
Node v12.21.0
```

I have 0.09 ETH on my wallet, which should be enough to cover the migration.

Can anybody help me here?

Answer (score 0):

This is the error:

```
 * Try:
      + Using an adequately funded account
      + If you are using a local Geth node, verify that your node is synced.
```

I think you should add more ETH to cover the migration. Testnet gas fees are way lower than mainnet, so do not take that value to justify mainnet deployments.

Comment: Hm okay, I thought the try-run gas estimation is more or less accurate

Comment: is there a way to see how much is actually needed?

Comment: It could be something else, but lets take it step by step and figure it out. Its best to start with the basics. Try adding a web3 confirmation, metamask will show you the gas estimate. I'm not sure if there is a better way to find this out

Comment: Do you have an article about adding a web3 confirmation? I just added another 0.09 ETH (0.18 in total now) -> still the same error.

Comment: Is your Geth node synced?

Comment: I don't use geth? Is this also needed?

Comment: Also increase gas limit

Comment: I thought I just need something like this:
live: {
   networkCheckTimeout: 10000,
   provider: () => {
      return new HDWalletProvider(
        mnemonic,
        `infura`
      );
   },
   network_id: "1",
  },

Answer (score 0):

I found a few helpful resources in this Discord group : https://discord.gg/MffMqPF3. The community is quite helpful as well.